# RxJava Multithreading with Realm - Realm access from incorrect thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

**Background**

I am using Realm within my app. When data is loaded it then undergoes intense processing therefore the processing occurs on a background thread.

The coding pattern in use is the Unit of Work pattern and Realm only exists within a repository under a DataManager. The idea here is that each repository can have a different database/file storage solution.

**What I have tried**

Below is an example of some similar code to what I have in my FooRespository class.

The idea here is that an instance of Realm is obtained, used to query the realm for objects of interest, return them and close the realm instance. Note that this is synchronous and at the end copies the objects from Realm to an unmanaged state.

```
public Observable<List<Foo>> getFoosById(List<String> fooIds) {

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(fooRealmConfiguration);

    RealmQuery<Foo> findFoosByIdQuery = realm.where(Foo.class);

    for(String id : fooIds) {

        findFoosByIdQuery.equalTo(Foo.FOO_ID_FIELD_NAME, id);
        findFoosByIdQuery.or();
    }

    return findFoosByIdQuery
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .doOnUnsubscribe(realm::close)
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
            .flatMap(foos -> Observable.just(new ArrayList<>(realm.copyFromRealm(foos))));
}
```

This code is later used in conjunction with the heavy processing code via RxJava:

```
dataManager.getFoosById(foo)
            .flatMap(this::processtheFoosInALongRunningProcess)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //could be Schedulers.computation() etc
            .subscribe(tileChannelSubscriber);
```

After reading the docs, my belief is that the above should work, as it is NOT asynchronous and therefore does not need a looper thread. I obtain the instance of realm within the same thread therefore it is not being passed between threads and neither are the objects.

**The problem**

When the above is executed I get

> Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed
>   on the thread they were created.

This doesn't seem right. The only thing I can think of is that the pool of Realm instances is getting me an existing instance created from another process using the main thread.

Comment: Will it work if you try to do something like `Observable.flatMap { dataManager.getFoosById(foo)`?

Comment: Do you mean to flatmap the whole chain I posted inside or just that first part?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think you need to fetch Realm object from the same thread which is `Schedulers.io` right? Probably be like
```Observable.flatMap(dataManager.getFoosById(foo))
            .flatMap(this::processtheFoosInALongRunningProcess)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //could be Schedulers.computation() etc
            .subscribe(tileChannelSubscriber);```
not sure about the syntax though

Comment: or does this one work? just to see if my assumption is correct :P
```realm.where(Foo.class)
            .findFoosByIdQuery.equalTo(Foo.FOO_ID_FIELD_NAME, id);
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .flatMap(this::processtheFoosInALongRunningProcess)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //could be Schedulers.computation() etc
            .subscribe(tileChannelSubscriber);```

Comment: I'll check and come back to you.

Comment: @GrahamSmith if I recall correctly, `copyFromRealm` doesn't actually remove the threading restrictions, just the automatic updates. I had to create a "copy constructor" of a non-Realm object that copied the field values into a new object last time I worked with Realm and threading. See this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/931

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix wrong, `copyFromRealm` detaches RealmObjects from the underlying Realm, and unmanaged copies are not thread-confined

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you're right, when I was having that issue there wasn't a copyFromRealm method yet, that's probably why I remembered that github issue (which actually has a link the the PR that added it)

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix ah yeah I guess it's *somewhat* new. `As discussed this breaks Realms zero-copy and consistency guarantees, but enables architectural patterns currently not supported by Realm.` Yup yup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kay so

```
return findFoosByIdQuery
        .findAll()
        .asObservable()
```

This happens on UI thread, because that's where you're calling it from initially

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Aaaaand then you're tinkering with them on `Schedulers.io()`.

Nope, that's not the same thread!

As much as I dislike the approach of *copying* from a *zero-copy* database, your current approach is riddled with issues due to misuse of `realmResults.asObservable()`, so here's a spoiler for what your code should be:

```
public Observable<List<Foo>> getFoosById(List<String> fooIds) {
   return Observable.defer(() -> {
       try(Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(fooRealmConfiguration)) { //try-finally also works
           RealmQuery<Foo> findFoosByIdQuery = realm.where(Foo.class);
           for(String id : fooIds) {
               findFoosByIdQuery.equalTo(FooFields.ID, id);
               findFoosByIdQuery.or(); // please guarantee this works?
           }
           RealmResults<Foo> results = findFoosByIdQuery.findAll();
           return Observable.just(realm.copyFromRealm(results));
       }
   }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Comment: Oh by the way, it's worth noting the fact that the other solution won't work because `asObservable()` will crash on a non-looping background thread. Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't alone in my thinking, what is the real point of asObservable() for RealmResults?

Comment: There's an example for it in my article https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149#.ll9uqyowi you'll see it when you get there (the short answer is that on looper threads aka the UI thread, it automatically adds a change listener for it that notifies you, and removes it when you unsubscribe)

Comment: Nice article - for the record I dumbed down a much more complex pipeline to just the bit I was confused over (there's Zip operations etc). I plan to upgrade Realm to get access to the IN operator too so I can avoid the unnecessary for loop with or().

Comment: Well once you detach the RealmObjects, you lose autoupdates and you copy out all elements, but you'll be able to toss them around between threads however you want.

Comment: Since I don't use Realm myself, it might be that my solution doesn't work as @EpicPandaForce mentioned. The reason for your exception is still the mixing of the threads. Just one comment/question: Why add `subscribeOn()` to `getFoosById()`? Isn't that better left open for the client to decide?

Comment: @Wolfram i guess that is true, the subscribeOn is not necessary, just to ensure it isn't on a foreground thread (but yes, your code wouldn't work, it'd crash in `asObservable`)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i'm curious about how should we make heavy computations outside the render thread (while avoiding object copy) and sending the resulting objects to the render thread with realm...

Comment: You can't avoid copying if you intend to off-load heavy computations to a background thread. The question is typically whether you can retain Realm's reactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are creating the instance outside of all your RxJava processing pipeline. Thus on the main thread (or whichever thread you are on, when calling `getFoosById()`.

Just because the method returns an Observable doesn't mean that it runs on another thread. Only the processing pipeline of the Observable created by the last statement of your `getFoosById()` method runs on the correct thread (the `filter()`, the `flatMap()` and all the processing done by the caller).

You thus have to ensure that the call of `getFoosById()`is already done on the thread used by `Schedulers.io()`.

One way to achieve this is by using `Observable.defer()`:

```
Observable.defer(() -> dataManager.getFoosById(foo))
            .flatMap(this::processtheFoosInALongRunningProcess)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //could be Schedulers.computation() etc
            .subscribe(tileChannelSubscriber);
```

Comment: Wolfram, I'm glad you saw this. I shall try in the morning. This code could easily be added to my DataManager that sits between the caller and the repository.